# Postgres query slower after deleting records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently deleted 5M bogus rows from a table, and 200K from another. And to my surprise the query plan cost increased exponentially. I ran a full vacuum and reindex database, but didn't seem to help.

Before rows deleted

```
Limit  (cost=272504.22..272504.23 rows=26 width=58)
   ->  Sort  (cost=272504.22..274814.51 rows=4620579 width=58)
         Sort Key: shoppe_orders.received_at DESC, shoppe_orders.id DESC
         ->  Seq Scan on shoppe_orders  (cost=114400.80..246164.89 rows=4620579 width=58)
               Filter: ((hashed SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  Unique  (cost=90697.67..114152.84 rows=41509 width=4)
                       ->  Gather Merge  (cost=90697.67..114132.08 rows=41509 width=4)
                             Workers Planned: 1
                             ->  Merge Join  (cost=89697.67..108711.37 rows=24417 width=4)
                                   Merge Cond: (shoppe_orders_1.id = shoppe_order_items.order_id)
                                   ->  Sort  (cost=89683.77..89750.22 rows=132906 width=4)
                                         Sort Key: shoppe_orders_1.id
                                         ->  Parallel Index Scan using index_shoppe_orders_on_store_id on shoppe_orders shoppe_orders_1  (cost=0.09..86121.70 rows=132906 width=4)
                                               Index Cond: (store_id = 1)
                                               Filter: (received_at IS NOT NULL)
                                   ->  Index Only Scan using index_shoppe_order_items_on_order_id on shoppe_order_items  (cost=0.09..18439.37 rows=1131822 width=4)
               SubPlan 2
                 ->  Unique  (cost=0.11..227.20 rows=25 width=4)
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.11..227.19 rows=25 width=4)
                             ->  Index Only Scan using index_shoppe_subscriptions_on_order_id on shoppe_subscriptions  (cost=0.03..6.24 rows=54 width=4)
                             ->  Index Scan using shoppe_orders_pkey on shoppe_orders shoppe_orders_2  (cost=0.09..4.09 rows=1 width=4)
                                   Index Cond: (id = shoppe_subscriptions.order_id)
                                   Filter: (store_id = 1)
```

after rows deleted

```
 Limit  (cost=19363626238.19..19363626240.97 rows=26 width=35)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=19363626238.19..19363663680.05 rows=349924 width=35)
         Workers Planned: 1
         ->  Sort  (cost=19363625238.18..19363625413.15 rows=349924 width=35)
               Sort Key: shoppe_orders.received_at DESC, shoppe_orders.id DESC
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on shoppe_orders  (cost=325.96..19363623243.46 rows=349924 width=35)
                     Filter: ((SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Materialize  (cost=4.60..82768.35 rows=482268 width=4)
                             ->  Unique  (cost=4.60..80402.08 rows=482268 width=4)
                                   ->  Merge Join  (cost=4.60..80133.38 rows=537399 width=4)
                                         Merge Cond: (shoppe_orders_1.id = shoppe_order_items.order_id)
                                         ->  Index Scan using shoppe_orders_pkey on shoppe_orders shoppe_orders_1  (cost=0.08..49400.20 rows=482268 width=4)
                                               Filter: (received_at IS NOT NULL)
                                         ->  Index Only Scan using index_shoppe_order_items_on_order_id on shoppe_order_items  (cost=0.08..28451.62 rows=883832 width=4)
                     SubPlan 2
                       ->  Unique  (cost=0.11..321.35 rows=47 width=4)
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.11..321.32 rows=47 width=4)
                                   ->  Index Only Scan using index_shoppe_subscriptions_on_order_id on shoppe_subscriptions  (cost=0.03..4.34 rows=78 width=4)
                                   ->  Index Scan using shoppe_orders_pkey on shoppe_orders shoppe_orders_2  (cost=0.08..4.06 rows=1 width=4)
                                         Index Cond: (id = shoppe_subscriptions.order_id)
                                         Filter: (received_at IS NOT NULL)
```

any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: You may have lost the table statistics. Have you tried running ANALYZE on your table ?

Comment: I did, but didn't do anything. :(

Comment: To get any useful help we need the actual query as well a complete `explain analyze` of same.